# Why doesn't dividing identical cases not matter anymore in combinatorics when related with probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider **six people are divided into two groups (with at least one person)**

Now if we find the ways that there will be a group with two and four, we have $\frac{6C4\cdot4C4}{2}$ because picking the four first is the same as picking the two first.

However, when we find the probability that there will be a group with two and four in the other, it becomes:
$|S|=2^6 - 2$

$|E| = 6C4\cdot4C4$, so $P = \frac{6C4\cdot4C4}{2^6 - 2}$

Why was dividing by 2 not necessary?

Comment: Your first claim -- that the number of ways is $\frac{1}{2}\binom64$ is incorrect. Note that once you pick your group of four, the group of two is immediately determined. You don't need to do any dividing by $2$.

Comment: $^{6}C_{4}$ and $^{6}C_{2}$ are the same cases but $^{6}C_{4}$ and $^{4}C_{4}$ are not. Also dividing by 2 is wrong for simultaneous events even if both the cases are the same (even though such cases won't arise). For example,$\frac{6+6}{2}=6$ but not $\frac{6×6}{2}$

Comment: I think I found my mistake: Yes you guys are correct but the reason I thought incorrectly was that you only divide by 2 if the groups are the same amount of people (right)? So if you made two groups of 3 people then you would divide by 2 since the groups are the same. Also @dobby, ins't this [3 people case] still a simultaneous event?

Comment: @user71207  Yes it is a simultaneous event. But you don't need to divide by two because even if the number of people in each team is the same,  the people themselves are different.

example: putting A,B,C in a team occurs simultaneously with putting D,E,F in another team. They are **two different events** occurring at **once**. You cannot put A,B,C in team 1 as well as in team 2 at the same time (if it is possible, you can say both groups are same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused about the basic concepts. So I'll try my best to explain the whole problem simpler so that you could understand where you're going wrong.

Imagine there are 6 people **A,B,C,D,E,F**

From these 6 people, if we take two people (say **A** and **B**) and put them into a separate team. The rest four people (**C,D,E,F**)  will simultaneously become the other team. Thus our purpose of splitting them into two teams is fulfilled!

Wait! we are not finished yet. Putting **A** and **B** in a separate team is only one possibility out of many.

Out of 6 people, 2 people can be selected in $^{6}C_{2}$ ways and 4 people from the remaining 4 people is $^{4}C_{4}$ ways which is equal to **1** (obviously! as the other 4 are automatically sorted, as mentioned before)

So the total number of ways teams of 2 people and 4 people can be formed = $^{6}C_{2}\times^{4}C_{4}$ (OR) $^{6}C_{2}$ ways  (as $^{4}C_{4}=1$)

Now we need to find the total number of ways in which 6 people can be split into two teams of different compositions (ie) Teams with 1 and 5 or teams with 2 and 4 and so on...

Which can be calculated as: $(^{6}C_{1}\times\ ^{5}C_{5}) + (^{6}C_{2}\times\ ^{4}C_{4}) + (^{6}C_{3}\times\ ^{3}C_{3}) + (^{6}C_{4}\times\ ^{2}C_{2}) + (^{6}C_{5}\times\ ^{1}C_{1})$

=$\ ^{6}C_{1} + ^{6}C_{2} + ^{6}C_{3} + ^{6}C_{4} + ^{6}C_{5}$

**NOTE 1**: We are **adding** each term because only one can occur at a time (ie) we cannot choose two compositions of teams simultaneuosly (I cannot split them into teams of **4 and 2** and **5 and 1** simultaneously. I can only do one of them at a time.). We **multiply** if two events were to occur simultaneously.

**NOTE 2:**  **Team 1** having 5 people and **Team 2** having 1 people is the same as **Team 1** having 1 people and **Team 2** having 5 people  (Secret: You can just rename the team! lol. The essence of a team is their constituting members). Thus we **divide the total possibilities by 2!** (As the total number of ways we can arrange the two teams is 2! . Similarly, if we were to split 6 people into 3 teams, the teams can be arranged in 3! ways) In other words, **order doesn't matter**

(ie) total possibilities = $\frac{^{6}C_{1} + ^{6}C_{2} + ^{6}C_{3} + ^{6}C_{4} + ^{6}C_{5}}{2!}=\frac{62}{2\times1}=31$

P(splitting into teams of 2 and 4 members)= $\frac{^6C_{2}\times^{4}C_{4}}{31}=\frac{^{6}C_{2}}{31}=\frac{15}{31}$

---

Now, coming to your query on why don't we divide by 2, I've already posted it in the comment section of your question. I hope that this helps you.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! I hope it will be able to help me with future questions as well. Your wording is very clear (and I often have trouble following combinatorics based solutions)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that I could help.